# (Typescript) compare types of two objects

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract base class with many different child classes extending it.  If given two instances of the class, is it possible to check if they have the same child type?

I wanted to do something like this, but typeof just returns "object" so it's pretty useless

```
compare(a: Parent, b: Parent): boolean {
    return typeof a === typeof b
}
```

Comment: @Osakr wouldn't instanceof require a type, not an instance, on the right side?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by comparing [the constructor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

```
compare(a: Parent, b: Parent): boolean {
    return a.constructor === b.constructor
}
```

But it isn't a rock-solid solution because the property `constructor` [can be reassigned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#Changing_the_constructor_of_an_object):

> The following example shows how to modify constructor value of generic objects. Only `true`, `1` and `"test"` will not be affected as they have read-only native constructors. This example shows that it is not always safe to rely on the `constructor` property of an object. […]